# "Failed to read Block"

Tags: bitcoin-core

I encountered a error whilst downloading Bitcoin-Qt on my Macbook version 10.6.8; it says "Failed to read block"
How do I fix this error without losing the bitcoins currently in my wallet?
Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that you are 'downloading Bitcoin-Qt'. Are you using a browser to download Bitcoin-Qt, or are you using Bitcoin-Qt to download the blockchain?

Comment: This question helped me with the same issue: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10295/bitcoin-qt-read-block-error

Comment: -reindex worked for me! thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Start the client with the `-reindex` command-line option.

Answer (score 1):

If you backup the wallet.dat file, then you should be able to remove everything else, and then Bitcoin-Qt will redownload the block chain.

Comment: This will work, but is overkill.